# How to subquery 2 SELECT each of them having JOIN and GROUPY

Tags: sql, subquery

I have 2 tables similar to these :

**Table `a` :**

| Date | Brand | Buy | Sale | Contract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-02 | Tesla | 0 | 0 | ABC |
| 22-01 | Fiat | 1 | 1 | FGE |
| 22-01 | Chevrolet | 0 | 0 | HUI |
| 22-06 | Fiat | 1 | 1 | AZE |
| 22-05 | Toyota | 1 | 0 | JIU |

**And Table `b` :**

| Brand | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Tesla | electric |
| Fiat | gasoline |
| Chevrolet | diesel |
| Fiat | diesel |
| Toyota | hybrid |

I manage to select all the brands that were purchased in 2022-01 of gasoline type :

```
SELECT a.Brand, COUNT(Contract) AS Bought
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.Brand = a.Brand AND b.TYPE = 'gasoline'
WHERE a.Buy = 1 AND a.Date = '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY a.Brand
```

Similarly, I can select all the brands that were sold between 0 and 3 months after 2022-01 of electric type:

```
SELECT a.Brand, COUNT(Contract) AS Sold
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.Brand = a.Brand AND b.TYPE = 'electric'
WHERE a.Sale = 1 AND a.Date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND ADD_MONTHS('2022-01-01', 3)
GROUP BY a.Brand
```

But I can't subquery the brands having both:

- were bought in 2022-01 of gasoline type
- AND sold between 0 and 3 months after 2022-01 of electric type

where should I make my subquery please? Could you show an example please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you're returning results only from table A you can use a semi-join here.

To implement both criteria use an *exists* correlation; the following is untested but hopefully is close enough to what you need:

```
select a.Brand, Count(*) as Sold
from a
where a.Sale = 1 and exists (
  select * from b 
  where b.Brand = a.Brand and (
    (b.type = 'electric' and a.Date between '2022-01-01' and ADD_MONTHS('2022-01-01', 3))
    or (b.type = 'gasoline' and a.Date = '2022-01-01')
  )
)
group by a.Brand;
```